# Retrieve multiple configuration keys from ini file based on dynamic list

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I'm not able to pass the values of a list to a `for` loop which will return the value assigned to it in config file at runtime.

My config file is `demo.ini`:

```
[DEMFILE]
Name='XYZABC'
Surname='TYUIO'
Code='123'
City='Kolkata'
```

I have a list in which I have parameters like below:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
mylist=['Name','Code']
mylist_count=len(mylist)
   
dmfg=config_object["DEMFILE"]


for i in range(mylist_count):
    getValue=dmfg[i] # ---> Throws error 
    print(f'The value of {i} is : {getValue}')
```

Expected Output for `getValue` is as shown below:

```
The value of Name is : XYZABC
The value of City is : Kolkata
```

I want whatever the values in list that should check in config file and return the output assigned to it.

For example: `Name` --> `XYZABC` (coming from config file).

Comment: You need the  element from `mylist`, not the index: `[dmfg[x] for x in mylist]`?

Comment: @ggorlen  : See mylist as [ 'Name' ] => that Name as some value in config file which is XYZABC that i want to return

Comment: Exactly... that's what my code suggestion is trying to do. What's `config_object` though?

Comment: @ggorlen  let me try the code

Comment: @ggorlen : it throwing error : `raise keyerror (key)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create an instance of the [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), read the .ini file and use the key rather than its index to retrieve the value:

```py
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> config = ConfigParser()
>>> config.read("demo.ini")
['demo.ini']
>>> keys = ["Name", "Code"]
>>> vals = [config["DEMFILE"][x] for x in keys]
>>> vals
["'XYZABC'", "'123'"]
```

If the quotes seem odd, config values [typically aren't quoted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Format). Either remove the quotes from the config or strip them with `[x[1:-1] for x in vals]`.

Comment: let me try your method

Comment: is it possible to get keys = [ ] initialise from file , my file as keys Name , City , Surname that should go into keys = [ Name , City , Surname ]

Comment: Yes that's possible. Store the list as a file in some format, say, an .ini file or one value per line and [read it into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list).

Comment: i have a file in which cutting the column 3 which as Name  surname city that i am trying to get into key with this command : `keys = [ x.split("|")[3].rstrip("\n") for x in open(dm.txt).readlines()]`  this values when passed to `vals = [config["DEMFILE"][x] for x in keys]` it fails keyerror

Comment: Maybe ask a new question or try debugging it by printing each `x` with `repr(x)` to see what it contains exactly. There might be whitespace or a case issue. I'm not sure what `dm.txt` contains. It'd have to be in the format `a|b|c|Name` I'd think. If it's a CSV file, better to use a [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) rather than trying to parse it by hand.

Comment: I will post it as new question just check in few minutes

Comment: can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836171/how-to-use-list-values-into-config