# How to read one column of a CSV file into a list of values

Tags: python, csv

I have the below data in the file `dm.txt`

```
A|B|Name
VB|C|City
SDF|JK|Code
```

Code to read the file and index into a separate config file:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("demo.ini")

# cutting the values of file from column 3 
keys = [ x.split("|")[2].rstrip("\n") for x in open(dm.txt).readlines()]
vals = [config["DEMFILE"][x] for x in keys]
print(vals)
```

It throws the error: `KeyError (keys)`. How can I read the third column of the CSV into a list?

Comment: Off by one error... indexes start at 0 then 1 then 2 etc... so you need to use 2 instead of 3 for the 3rd key. In this statement x.split("|")[3] you are asking for the 4th item in the split and there are only 3 items in your split, hence the keyError message

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you write it more stretched out and refactor it after you made it work (e.g. using list comprehension).

### Error

The `open` command takes the file as a string. Therefore it should be `open("dm.txt", "r")`.

#### Note

This does fix the original issue, but there are possible other issues when using this line. This is not how to use `open` properly. Use the corresponding *context manager* instead.

As stated before write out your code one step after another and refactor it later.

#### Solution

```py
with open("a.txt", "r") as f:
    keys = (line.split("|")[2].rstrip("\n") for line in f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `dm.txt` needs quotes around it -- it's a string, not an object, so your code won't run at all as-is, and you should get a pretty clear `NameError` about that.

Secondly, please don't try to parse CSVs by hand, even if they're trivial. Use the [builtin CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and access `row[2]` (the third column) in each row:

```py
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> with open("dm.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|")
...     keys = [row[2] for row in reader]
...
>>> keys
['Name', 'City', 'Code']
```

Now you can [key into your config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834996/6243352) using the elements of the `keys` list.

Answer (score 0):

Off by one error... indexes start at 0 then 1 then 2 etc... so you need to use 2 instead of 3 for the 3rd key. In this statement x.split("|")[3] you are asking for the 4th item in the split and there are only 3 items in your split, hence the keyError message.

I recommend using

```
keys = [ x.split("|")[2].rstrip("\n") for x in open("dm.txt").readlines()]
```

Additionally:

Try using full paths in read() and open() functions
i.e:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("C:\\PathToIni\\demo.ini")

# cutting the values of file from column 3 
keys = [ x.split("|")[2].rstrip("\n") for x in open("C:\\PathToTxt\\dm.txt").readlines()]
vals = [config["DEMFILE"][x] for x in keys]
print(vals)
```

This outputs:

```
["'XYZABC'", "'Kolkata'", "'123'"]
```

for me using the two files:

**dm.txt:**

```
A|B|Name
VB|C|City
SDF|JK|Code
```

**demo.ini**

```
[DEMFILE]
Name='XYZABC'
Surname='TYUIO'
Code='123'
City='Kolkata'
```

This answer also shows how to create a generic agnostic relative path
[Relative paths in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Comment: its type error i have corrected , then also it gets fail

Comment: raise KeyError(key)

Comment: first part is their here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834778/retrieve-multiple-configuration-keys-from-ini-file-based-on-dynamic-list just read this here in this question i have getting from file it gets fail

Comment: @SvenTUM is correct. dm.txt needs quotations around it.